# Incorrect argument to decltype

Tags: c++, templates, winapi, decltype

I asked two days ago about creating threads to run non-static class methods with the Win32 API, and I almost got a solution but there is something confusing me, so I'm asking this question before posting the answer in my previous question.

I'm trying to use this code to thread a function with an unknown return type:

```
template <class R, R func() >
unsigned int usualfunc() {
   func();
   return 1;
}

template <class R>
int Start(R(*func)()) {
   typedef decltype(&usualfunc<int, func>) D; // I get the error here , I can't get the address of the template function directly I need this
   D p = &usualfunc<R, func>;
   uintptr_t add = (uintptr_t)p;
   CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)add, 0, 0, 0);
   func();
   return 1;
}

int main() {
   Start(ltest);
}
```

When I try to compile the above code, I get :

> error 3556 'usualfunc': incorrect argument to 'decltype'

The error description is described on MSDN:

[Compiler Error C3556](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394161.aspx)

However, I tried another code before this, and it works just fine, but I wasn't very good with the syntax:

```
template <class R, R func() >
unsigned int usualfunc() {
   func();
   return 1;
}

 template <class R,R func()>
int Start() {
   typedef decltype(&usualfunc<int, func>) D; // works well
   D p = &usualfunc<R, func>;
   uintptr_t add = (uintptr_t)p;
   CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)add, 0, 0, 0);
   func();
   return 1;
}

int main() {
   Start<int,ltest>(); // works
}
```

I know this code is enough, but I'd like to use `Start(ltest)` instead of `Start<int,ltest>()`.

Note: no one say that I should use the function as parameter in `usualfunction`, I'm using it as a template parameter because `CreateThread()` can't pass a function as a parameter.

Comment: "but wasn't very good in the syntax", on what premise?

Comment: Please edit your code to be a MCVE

Comment: sorry I am not very good at English, I meant that writing `Start<int,ltest>();` is more complex than `Start(ltest)` especially when I use it with class members , my current code works like this : `class testt {unsigned int testf() {.....}}; testt *tt = new testt; Thread t; t.Set<testt, unsigned int, &testt::testf>(tt);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template parameters must be known at compile-time. However you attempt to use the normal function parameter `func` as a template argument.

In the second code you give a template parameter as the template argument, which is fine.

Your first code is wrong for a similar reason as this code:

```
template<int X> void f() { }

int main(int argc, char **argv) { f<argc>(); }
```

although the error message is a bit more obscure.

---

Since C++17 you can get the syntax you want by making this modification to your second code:

```
template <auto func>
int Start() {
    using R = decltype(func());
    // proceed as before...
```

and call it as `Start<ltest>();`.

Prior to C++17 you could use a macro with your second code:

```
#define START(func) Start<decltype(func()), func>
```

Comment: I tried but auto templates aren't supported in vs 2015 which I'm using and macros can't be an option when using it as a class member . isn't there any method to use the function parameter as type ?

Comment: You can still use the macro or just write out the decltype

Comment: I want to use the function as the constructor of the class but I couldn't because I can't use template parameters with  constructors so I used it as member and it works but as I said the problem only in the using of the function , really it isn't a big thing to worry about .

Comment: clang 6 and 5 support auto ? if yes I have clang-cl 5 which should be able to do it

Comment: @dev65 use the flag `-std=c++17`

Comment: I added this to the command line in visual studio : -Xclang -std=c++17

Answer (score 0):

as I'm using visual studio 2015 and can't use auto templates I used the macros as M.M said and ended with this

```
Thread t;
t.SetFunc(ltest);
t.SetMember(testt, testf, tt); // class type , member function , pointer to class , it's like this : testt::testf , I can use this outside of class
t.SetMember(testt, testf, this); // from a member of the class , this is a pointer to the class , as I use this inside the member I can also thread private members here
```

Answer (score 0):

with clang-cl 5 or 6 in visual studio 2015 :

```
template <auto func>
int Start() {
   using R = decltype(func());
   typedef decltype(&usualfunc<R, func>) D;
   D p = &usualfunc<R, func>;
   uintptr_t add = (uintptr_t)p;
   CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)add, 0, 0, 0);
   return 1;
}
```

this compiled well